# Is CheckBox checked or not in RDL reportview

Tags: reporting-services, rdl

I've 2 checkboxs(actually two rectangles) in a report page. The object from the database, returns boolean value. If It returns yes, I want to checked "Yes" or not, the other one must be checked.

I'm newbie in RDL reporting project. How can I add an expression for this?

[image: This is the image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Right Click you Rectangle and go to Insert | Indicator
2. When the Indicator window opens, Select the middle option in the "Symbols" Section (has a cross, exclamation and tick)
3. Press OK, then Right Click the Indicator and click Indicator Properties
4. Go to Value and States. In the list of States at the bottom, delete the X and the exclamation. Set the Tick to have Start = 1 and End = 1
5. In the Value field enter `=Iif(Fields!<<fieldname>>.Value = True, 1, 0)` (obviously replace <> with the name of your field
6. In the States Measurement Unit field, select "Numeric"

Here's a snap of how to do it:

[image: Here's how to do it]

What this will do is evaluate that Iif statement and, if your field is true, will return a 1. The indicator will see that 1 and place a Green tick in the Rectangle.

Hope that helps, drop a comment here if you struggle.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using a Function or Stored Procedure Object from the database.
Whatever the object returns, declare a variable, and assign the value from the object to the variable (is one way of doing it).

Then you can use:

```
if(variable == True)
{
   CheckBoxYes.Checked = true;
}
```

Comment: I'm using a sql select query. In rdl page, I don't have a checkbox control, I'm using rectangles and I don't know where to write code.

Comment: @baros That's why you need to give full details when asking questions.

Comment: I found this. http://basireddysubbareddy.blogspot.com.tr/2013/06/display-checkbox-on-report-ssrs.html   =IIF(676160001=676160001, chr(0254),chr(0168))  This ode makes checked sign. But I don't know how to compare with the value from the db object? First(Fields!Email.Value, "Customer")   @Werner van den Heever